# (JAVA) Erro no foreach

Tags: java, foreach, for

por que ocorre um erro na execução do código abaixo se eu remover o break? O valor do ArrayList clientes não é atualizado sempre que termina o for?

```
            for (Cliente cliente : clientes) {
                if (identificacao==cliente.getIdentificacao()) {
                    existeid = true;
                    exibeCliente(cliente,false);
                    System.out.println("Confirma exclusão? 1- SIM 2- NÃO");
                    op=sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();

                    if (op==1) {
                        clientes.remove(cliente);
                        System.out.println("Excluído com sucesso!");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Exclusão cancelada!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at tabajaraAirlines.FicharioCliente.excluir(FicharioCliente.java:233)
 at tabajaraAirlines.Principal.main(Principal.java:39)

Comment: se eu deixar o break roda normalmente, mas minha dúvida é por que o erro ocorre se eu remover ele

Answer (score 1):

Não pode remover o elemento com `remove` a partir da lista à medida que percorre com `foreach` pois invalida o iterador utilizado internamente:

```
for (Cliente cliente : clientes) {
    if (identificacao==cliente.getIdentificacao()) {
        ...
        if (op==1) {
            clientes.remove(cliente); // <-- aqui
            ...
```

O iterador tem na verdade métodos de adição e remoção precisamente para esse caso. Isso obriga-o no entanto a construir o laço/ciclo de forma diferente, utilizando diretamente o iterador:

```
Iterator<Cliente> iter = clientes.iterator(); //obter o iterador para a lista
while(iter.hasNext()){ //enquanto o iterador não chegou ao fim
    Cliente cliente = iter.next(); //obter o elemento corrente pelo iterador
    if (identificacao==cliente.getIdentificacao()) {
        ...
        if (op==1) {
            iter.remove(); // remoção a partir do iterador
            ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito. Quanto ao else, ele só executa uma vez,  a indentação do código é que estava ruim aqui no site. Já fiz a correção :D.